# Mac Microsoft Word 2011 stripping RTL format from doc

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-word-2011

I copyedit articles for a psych journal using Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac. I occasionally get articles with right-to-left formatting (in English), and I can't seem to rid the doc of this format. Bad enough that I can't get it out of the original (or copies of the) document, but it then ends up in my template and any other documents I copy and paste to, even when I think I've removed it.

The only work-around I've found is to ask the author to send me a new copy of the article, but I'm bound to run into a non-tech-savvy author at some point.

Any suggestions? Thanks--Jenny

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment so I suggest:

1. For a misbehaved document, check **Word Options, Advanced, Show document content, Document view: Left-to-right**.
2. Also, **Customize, Home Tab**, select **Left-to-Right Text Direction, Add, OK**.

I don't have Word 2011 to check this so may not work even if it would have done for a different version!

Step 1. may be sufficient for the sample document (or at least rule out a possible fix) and Step 2. is intended to make it easier to switch RTL>LTR at will by making visible little pilcrows with arrows in the Paragraph section of the Home tab.

Comment: Unfortunately these options don't seem to exist in Word for Mac 2011